# Joomla database connection infinite loop

Tags: database, loops, joomla, infinite

My Joomla site located on first machine and a database on second.
I updated the configuration.php parameters `$host`, `$user`, `$password` and`$db`
But I got error saying an infinite loop has been detected.

I'm running Joomla version: 1.7.3 stable.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are it is a php error in your configuration.php file - possibly your password includes a quote or some other character than breaks the PHP - introducing a syntax error.

As a quick test - you could create a .php file (perhaps test.php) that includes 'configuration.php'. Load your test.php file and see if you get an error.

Alternatively - inspect your configuration.php file manually to spot the error. If you edited it manually you may have deleted a semi-colon for example.

Hope that helps.